# Pascal program sort of freezes after input

Tags: pascal

I am trying to input
Z: 20202020
X: 202020
C: 2020

But after that, my terminal doesn't show anything. Why is that? I have tried with some other input and it works just fine.

Edit: I realized that the same problem occurs whenever the X input is more than 5 digit.

```
program PowerTower;
Uses Math;
var
x,
z: real;
c: int64;
hasil : real;

function pembulatan(o: real): int64;
begin
pembulatan:= Round(o);
end;


function dopower(h,y: real): 
real;
begin
  dopower:= power(h,y)
end;


function ayam(a, b: real) : real;
begin
  begin
    if (b=0) then
      ayam := 1
    else
      ayam:= dopower(a,ayam(a, b-1));
  end;
end;

begin
readln(z);
readln(x);
readln(c);
hasil:= ayam(z, x);

writeln(pembulatan(hasil) mod c);
readln;
end.
```

Comment: You get a [stack overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow) due to too deep [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)).

Comment: Is there any way to fix it? Or my program simply incapable of doing more than 5 digit input on variable x

Comment: You can use iteration instead of recursion (at least as long as no other issues appear, like floating-point overflow).

Comment: What @AndreasRejbrand says about iteration is quite correct.  Every recursive calculation has at least one iterative equivalent.  See f.i. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159590/way-to-go-from-recursion-to-iteration.  Btw you *still* have not told us which Pascal implementation you are using.  Telling us that would help us know whether we can reproduce the problems you are having.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm reading it correctly but `ayam(a, b)` seems to compute `a` to the power of `b!` (`b` factorial). Is that what you intend? Also be careful about doing exact check for equality when using `real` numbers (like your `if (b=0)`).

Comment: Definitely lurker is correct. When you input bigger numbers the "resolution" of the number decreases, up to the point that subtracting 1 does not go to a precise zero, and your recursion goes forever. You could check for "<= 0", that would work if you don't need negative numbers. Last note: please don't use parentheses in pascal IFs, it is not C!

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica "please don't use parentheses in pascal IFs"  Why do you say that?  Pascal is fine with parenthesized IFs ... and they help beginners avoid tripping over operator precedence ...

Comment: @MartynA, well, I was referring only to unnecessary ones, like "if (b=0) then ...", which BTW is the only IF found in the OP code.

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica:  Oh, ok,  thanks.  I was only asking because I *think* the OP's `if ()` came from my answer to a previous q of his.